# I have 3.8.3 but i want to use 3.7

Tags: python, pycharm

how can I install python 3.7 and use it?

I am facing an error at the time of installation:

```
C:\Users\admin\PycharmProject\virtual_mouse>pip install mediapipe <br>
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mediapipe<br>
ERROR: No matching distribution found for mediapipe
```

Comment: You can uninstall python 3.8.3 and install python 3.7

Comment: Also, if you don't want to uninstall python 3.8.3, you can install python 3.7: https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-370/  and edit the environment variables to set all paths of python 3.7 to the top. This will always load python 3.7 unless you mention the version

Comment: if you have anaconda you can use `conda create --name myenv python=3.7`

Comment: I see that mediapipe available for py 3.8 as well.  Maybe you need to use pip3 instead of pip.  You can verify that by inspecting `which pipe`.

Answer (score 2):

You can configure the Python interpreter using the PyCharm settings

- `File` --> `Setting`
- In left side in `project` section --> `Project interpreter`
- Select desired `Project interpreter`
- <kbd>Apply</kbd> + <kbd>OK</kbd>

If it's not listed add it using the plus sign.

- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html#add_new_project_interpreter

Answer (score 0):

You can download Python 3.7 at [the official Python website's version archive](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-370/).

Depending on how you're OS is set up, you may need to uninstall whatever version is currently installed before installing 3.7.

Edit: I just saw you are using PyCharm. This does not apply to PyCharm; another answer under your post already explains how to apply a different version there.

Answer (score 0):

You have also the possibility to create a new conda environment to install a new version of python. So you can manage in local multiple versions of python:

conda create -n myenv python=3.7